# how to clear/hide mysql errors from command prompt

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql command responses in my script

When database connection was lost, MySQL would fail to response queries & at that time MySQL error will be shown in command prompt like

```
mysql -u root TEST -e "show tables"
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'X.X.X.X' (111)
```

I am in-need to hide that MySQL error from command prompt when i execute the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redirect standard error, just like you would any other command if you don't want to see errors.

```
mysql -u root TEST -e "show tables" 2>/dev/null
```

If you also want to hide the normal output, redirect standard output as well:

```
mysql -u root TEST -e "show tables" >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: working. But another conflict, I need to hide show tables output too.

Comment: So redirect standard output. But if you hide the output, what's the point of doing the query?

Comment: When using >>/dev/null it self. "Show tables" output was not shown. But MySQL errors were visible. Yours reply is working for me in reverse case.

Comment: `>` redirects standard ouput, `2>` redirects standard error. You can mix and match them.

Comment: I need to check whether i have access and privileges for that specific database.

Comment: Why is that curious? `&>filename` is an abbreviation for `>filename 2>&1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try "\! clear" , it will execute clear shell command."\!" is used to execute shell command.

```
mysql> \! clear
```

in *nix it will clear your command prompt.